# Drag`n`drop in Salesforce mobile app

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, mobile, js

Did anyone managed to use drag'n'drop feature in Salesforce mobile app (LWC)? I tried [Sortable js](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable), and simply adding `draggable='true'` as well, both work on Salesforce desktop version and on mobile browsers (Chrome, Safari), but on mobile app - none.

Comment: to use it on mobile you need to add mobile events as well for e.g ontouch, ontouchstart. https://w3c.github.io/touch-events/#event-touchstart

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml
I adapted first example from this site to LWC and it works. But - why then Sortable.js works on mobile Safari, but not on mobile Salesforce?!